# Mic is only picking up vibrations

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, microphone

Literally vibrations, when on the recording devices pane, the only way i can get the mic to show it is picking up audio is by tapping the headphones on my desk. I have uninstalled and reinstalled realtek audio drivers, and have gotten my entire audio chipset for my MSI X99S SLI PLUS from their website. I have tried 2 different mics, in 2 different audio ports, all 4 configurations all have the same results, talking into the mic has no effect. I have unplugged and replugged, restarted the computer, and made sure that teh device is enabled and that it is the default audio device, and am at my wits end. Anyone have any other tips?

Edit: Upping the sensitivity means that smaller vibrations are picked up, but still no voice or real sound of any kind is noted. Operating system is win7 64 bit.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check the microphone volume in the mixer or the sound option in the control panel (recording tab)?

Comment: @JuliePelletier In the control panel recording tab

Comment: That tab is in the control panel -> sound in classic view or control panel->hardware and sound->sound in category view.

Comment: @JuliePelletier control panel > Hardware and Sound > manage audio devices > recording is how i got the the screen I'm on.

Comment: OK, so what does it show for your microphone status?

Comment: @JuliePelletier The mic recognizes as plugged in, and on. it shows that it is picking up, if the headphones are tapped on something solid. (the headphones attached to the mic) and is unmuted, turned up.